# Is there any difference between "content" and "willing"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Is there any difference between "content" and "willing"? If there is a difference, I would like to know in what context would you use the word "content" instead of using the word "willing"?

Comment: Did you check the dictionary definitions for those words?

Comment: First read [this](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/content2_1) and then come to [this](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/willing). Not much difference. Choice of usage depends on the situation and you.

Comment: Yes I did, seems like there is not much difference. But I was just wondering why do we need to have two words with the exactly same meaning. There must be some some situation that ones would choose one word over another word. So in what context would you choose to use "content" over "willing"? Which one is more formal? Which one do people use in conversation? Which one do people think it sounds more natural? Or if these two words can be used interchangeably in every situation, I'm sorry for asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experiences in everyday English it's fairly rare for *content* to be used this way, though I think anyone hearing "content to [verb]" would understand. The words *content* and *willing* are definitely **not** interchangeable in every situation, or even in any situation but this one.

I think that you could make a case that the words have slightly different connotations: a person that is *willing* to wait is someone that will wait if necessary, while someone that is *content* to wait is satisfied with waiting. But I don't think that there are any situations where using one wording would be natural and the other odd.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to vote this up but I'm not allowed to do so as my reputation is less than 15.